# semy API is built on nodejs , I'm using a looger package that shows strangers requests comes to my API that I don't know about

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, digital-ocean

my API is built on nodejs , I'm using a looger package that shows strangers requests comes to my API that I don't know about these requests, requests like /.env, /PHP files, all requests as shown in the image below do not exists in my API or frontend

my API deployed in **digital ocean** company.

[image]

Comment: Bot scanners looking for vulnerabilities to exploit.

Comment: Do I have to worry or it's a normal thing?